# Macro variables inside data step

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I need to save the value of a certain variable in a data step in a macro and then use that macro in the same data step. i tried with `SYMPUT`, but if I've understood correctly a macro variable created that way cannot be used inside the same data step (it's assigned at the end of the data step, I guess?)

Here is a simplified example. I have a list of data fields `t1,...,t100` representing something happening at certain times, events being represented by numbers, and a data field `t_start` giving me the starting time for the process in which I'm interested for every observation. I want to check if I have all the data, and drop the observation otherwise. I want to proceed as follows.

```
DATA WANT;
    SET HAVE;

    CALL SYMPUT('START_TIME', t_start);

    DO I=&START_TIME. TO 100;
        IF t_&I. = . THEN DELETE;
    END;
RUN;
```

This doesn't work, I think for the reasons mentioned above. Is there a workaround?

Remarks:

1. I simplified the situation, the real case I'm looking at is more complex (e.g. the variables are not called `t1,...t100` but something with a bit more structure). If possible, I would like to get something as close to the approach I gave above as possible, as different solutions might not be applicable to my case. Of course, if this is not possible then any solution is more than welcome!
2. I tried looking at `RESOLVE`, but it doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for (or at least I don't understand it well enough to make it do what i desire).
3. As a last resort, I could try to solve the problem using two data steps, one defining the macro variables, the other one using it to check and delete the undesired observations. I would prefer avoiding this solution if possible.

---

**Update:** I solved the problem using arrays, as suggested in the solutions.

Comment: Can you use arrays? Why can't you replace start_time with t_start directly? That wouldn't affect anything in the example show, but the `t_&i` will not work because you don't have an I macro variable. I suspect you really need arrays but without more details that's all I can say now.

Comment: @Reeza Using  `t_start` directly unfortunately won't work in my "true" case, because in `t_start` i have a string, and only a part of the string is the particle of the other variables (the `I`). Maybe there's a way to do it like that, I'll try on Monday if i don't find any direct solution.

Comment: If you have a string that won't work anyways as indicated.

Comment: @Reeza Yes, I would have to work a bit on the `START_TIME` variable, e.g. by `%LET START_TIME_BIS = %SUBSTR(START_TIME,1,2);` or something like that. But the line of reasoning would remain the same.

Comment: No reason you can't do that in a data step either though, in fact it's easier, no need for %SYSFUNC() and you can use COMPRESS() to remove characters if needed.

Comment: SAS doesn't really have the concept of vectors, as to what you're referring, it's arrays which are just a reference to a variable list.

Comment: @Reeza Right, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the value of the `dataset` variables `t_start` and  `i` to figure out which variable to test.  That is what arrays are for.

```
DATA WANT;
  SET HAVE;
  array t t1-t100;
  DO I=t_start TO 100;
    IF t(i) = . THEN DELETE;
  END;
RUN;
```

No need for macro variables, much less macro variables that can travel backwards in time and modify the code of a data step after it has already started running.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a better approach using arrays. 
Given what you've posted, this works. If it doesn't match what you need, please post more details about your situation.

```
data demo;
array t(10);
do row=1 to 100;
do i=1 to 10;
t(i)=rand('integer', 1, 5);
end;
start = rand('integer', 1, 10);
output;
end;
run;

data test;
set demo;

array t(10);



do i=start to dim(t);
if t(i) < 2 then do;
    delete;
    leave;*exits loop;
end;
end;

run;
```

Comment: Given your recent comment, you'll need to show more details then because it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i'll take a good look at it and see if I can adapt it to what i need. Essentially my original question asks on how I can use data of the table I'm working on to create macros, and use the macros in the same data step.

Comment: Macro variables not macros - big difference. And there's not an easy way, which is why I'm suggesting arrays with indexes, which seems all you really need. Macro variables are nicer of course and I wish SAS had a way to change the index of your arrays on the fly, but sadly it doesn't. It's the use of the T_&i that is problematic, though you could just use a macro loop and wrap the whole thing in a macro to get around that if necessary. I just think avoiding macros & macro variables will be easier in the long run.

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot. I'll try and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: There is no need for `leave` since it will never execute. The `delete` will end the current iteration of the data step.

Answer (score 1):

When a data step is running the step has been 'compiled' and all ampersand ( `&` ) macro variable resolutions have already been resolved.  A running compiled step can not alter its source code.

If you submitted your code twice, the first time would log a `WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference not resolved.`  The second time would not have the warning, and would be using the value populated from the **prior** submission.

Suppose your data record has many variables, and two sentinel variables whose values are the **names** of the variables that mark the start and stop of some processing to occur.  While an unwieldy data construct, you can use an array to mediate access to the variant set of variables to be processed.

For example:

```
data have;
input 
 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h start $ stop $ ; datalines;
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  d  e
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18  a  b
 0  1  1  2  3  5  8 11  c  h
 1  1  1  1  1  .  1  1  a  e  wont be deleted because . is at f
 1  2  3  4  .  6  7  8  a  h
run;

data want;
  set have;
  array num a--h;
  do i = 1 to dim(num);
    if vname(num(i)) = start then startindex=i;
    if vname(num(i)) = stop  then stopindex=i;
  end;

  do i = min(startindex,stopindex) to max(startindex,stopindex);
    if missing(num(i)) then delete;
  end;
run;
```